# Issue with pattern program using loops

Tags: python, python-2.7, design-patterns

I'm writing a program that takes two inputs, number of lines and number of cheers as input. The number of lines is how many lines the user wants to print out and the number of cheers are in the format that 1 cheer is the word "GO" and two cheers are two "GO" s ...and their is the word "BUDDY" within two neighboring GO's. And each new line has to be indented 3 spaces more then the one before. And this is the program I've come up with:

```
lines = input("Lines= ")
cheers = input("Cheers= ")
if cheers == 1:
    i = 1
    space = 0
    S = ""
    while i<=lines:
        S=S+(" "*space)+"GO \n"
        i += 1
        space+=3
    print S
else:
    n = 1
    cheer1 = "GO BUDDY "
    cheer2 = "GO"
    space = 0
    while n<= cheers:
        print (" "*space)+(cheer1*cheers)+cheer2
        space+=3
        n += 1
```

But the problem with this is that it doesn't print out the right number of GO's in the number of cheers. How can I modify my code to fix this problem? This is the output format I want to get :

[image: This is the format of the ouput I want to get]

Answer (score 1):

```
def greet(lines, cheers):
    i = 0
    line_str = ""
    while i < cheers: # Build the line string
        i += 1
        line_str += "GO" if i == cheers else "GO BUDDY "

    i = 0 
    while i < lines: #Print each line
        print(" "*(i*3) + line_str)
        i += 1

greet(2,1)
greet(4,3)
greet(2,4)
```

Comment: That's exactly the same output as my program. I need as many "GO" words in one line as the number given to 'cheers' ... e.g; for lines = 3 and cheers = 3 output should be "GO BUDDY GO BUDDY GO" ..which has 3 "GO" words.

Comment: You can try it now @HogRider123

Answer (score 1):

Often in Python you don't need any loops

```
lines = int(input('Lines= '))
cheers = int(input('Cheers= '))

line = ' BUDDY '.join(['GO']*cheers)
for i in range(cheers):
     print(' '*(i*3) + line)
```

Comment: Yes you are right, actually I was asked specifically to write the code using loops.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
def greet(lines, cheers):
    for i in range (lines):
        output = (" ") * i + "Go"

        for j in range (cheers):
            if cheers == 1:
                print output
                break
            output += "Budddy Go"
        print output
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: put if cheer == 1 block inside cheers loop. I'll update the code